# Unwanted space after author name when using \citep

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am new to LaTeX and am having trouble when using \citep. Whenever I use it there is an extra space that is inserted after the author and before the comma. This is an example of what I get:

> known as the response ratio (see page 30 of Borenstein et al. , 2009).

When I want this:

> known as the response ratio (see page 30 of Borenstein et al., 2009).

I made example code to demonstrate the issue.

TeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

known as the response ratio \citep[see page 30 of][]{BO&HE&HI&RO09}.

\bibliographystyle{authordate4}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

And the contents of the Bib file:

```
@book{BO&HE&HI&RO09,
AUTHOR =       {Borenstein, M. and Hedges, L. V. and Higgins, J. P. T. and Rothstein, H. R.},
TITLE =        {Introduction to {M}eta-{A}nalysis},
PUBLISHER =    {Wiley},
YEAR =         {2009},
address =      {Chichester, West Sussex}
}
```

I am using linux and my editor is Texmaker if that matters. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:
I have played around with this a little more and there is no issue if there is only one author. This makes me think that it might have something to do with how the author list is being abbreviated

Comment: I think you're lucky that it works with `natbib`, the `bst` file seems to be from 1990(!??!) and the space after `et al.` is hardwired into the `bst` file, do either you make your own renamed version of `authordate4.bst` and edit it, or your should find another bibliography style file to use.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I don't quite understand. Where do I find the bst file? Also I installed latex from the linux mint repositories so maybe that is why the files are older. Is there some place to get up to date versions of things?

Comment: Dug around my system a bit more and found the bst file. So I understand now why my issue was happening. Thanks again @daleif. This question can be closed thanks.