# Unwanted space between author name with at al. and year when using \citep

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib

I am using `authordate` bibliography style to cite my references but when I use `\citep` an extra space is inserted after the author and before the comma. 
What I get is this:

> The area of a triangle and their derivatives (Talischi et al. , 2009)
>   are given by...

And what I want is:

> The area of a triangle here and their derivatives (Talischi et al.,
>   2009) are given by...

My code is:

```
\documentclass[msc,wide,cover,hidelinks,nonomencl,bibkey]{Thesis_AXL_en}
\usepackage{natbib}

    \begin{document}
    The area of a triangle and their derivatives \citep{Talischi_et_al2012b} are given by...

    \bibliographystyle{authordate1-4}
    \bibliography{References}
    \end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file is:

```
@Article{Talischi_et_al2012b,
    author       = {Talischi, C. and Paulino, G.H. and Pereira, A. and Menezes, I.F.M.},
    title        = {\textbf{PolyTop: a Matlab implementation of a general topology optimization framework using unstructured polygonal finite element meshes}},
    journal      = {Structural and Multidisciplinary Optimization},
    volume       = {45},
    number       = {3},
    pages        = {329--357},
    year         = {2012},
    publisher    = {Springer}
}
```

Searching I found the topic [Unwanted space after author name when using \citep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311547/unwanted-space-after-author-name-when-using-citep), but I don't have experience in dealing with `.bst` files and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: The `authordate` styles are *ancient*, and I doubt they are designed for use with `natbib`. Are you want to use them? There are plenty of other author-date style files around. Also, you need to post a link to your documentclass file.

Comment: @Alan Munn, I must use this documentclass because it is the one my university uses. And it is big, it wouldn't fit in here due to the number of characters.

Comment: That's why I asked you to post a link to it, not the class itself.

Comment: Can't you use a different bibliography style with their class?

Comment: In fact, I can, but it means I  have to rewrite all my dissertation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `authordate` styles are very old, and your example doesn't actually show which of the 4 versions you are using, as there is no bibliography style `authordate1-4`.  However, I assume the versions of the styles are similar, so I will show you how to solve the problem for `authordate1.bst` and you can apply the same solution to the others if needed.

First, make a copy of `authordate1.bst` and called it `authordate1-nospace.bst`.  Put this copy into the same folder as your document (or into your local `texmf` folder if you are likely to use the style for other documents.)

To locate the file you can type the following from the terminal and use that path to find it.

```
kpsewhich authordate1.bst
```

On (or around) line 1033 of the file, you should find

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " {\em et~al.\ }\relax" * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " {\em et~al.\ }\relax" * }
            { " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Change the line

```
{ pop$ " {\em et~al.\ }\relax" * }
```

to

```
{ pop$ " {\em et~al.}\relax" * } % removed hard coded space here
```

and save the file. Then in your document use:

```
\bibliographystyle{authordate1-nospace}
```

The same modification should work for the other versions of the `.bst` files.

I've made the minimal change to the `.bst` file that solves the problem you describe. There are a couple of other places in which there is a hard-coded space after `et~al` in the file. If you encounter further spacing problems of the same sort you could experiment with removing those spaces too, but they may be necessary, and so you should *not* change any of the others unless you have good reason to.

Here's a full example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Talischi_et_al2012b,
    author       = {Talischi, C. and Paulino, G.H. and Pereira, A. and Menezes, I.F.M.},
    title        = {\textbf{PolyTop: a Matlab implementation of a general topology optimization framework using unstructured polygonal finite element meshes}},
    journal      = {Structural and Multidisciplinary Optimization},
    volume       = {45},
    number       = {3},
    pages        = {329--357},
    year         = {2012},
    publisher    = {Springer}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
    The area of a triangle and their derivatives \citep{Talischi_et_al2012b} are given by...

\bibliographystyle{authordate1-nospace}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]